# AngularJS: Sort 2-dim Array within directive?

Tags: angularjs

i populate an array (kind of a model) with objects. **How can I sort this array by 'title'?**

```
// For ...
var item = {title: title, src: file};
images.push(item);

// How to sort?
images.sortBy('title')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort an array, use Array.sort with a custom sorting function.

```
images.sort(alphabeticallyByTitle);

function alphabeticallyByTitle(a, b){
    if (a.title < b.title){
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.title > b.title){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A natural sort requires a much hairier sorting function. Check out this article for a good write-up and some sample code: http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1671288

Comment: Well, thats 'alphabeticallyByTitle' but thats different than MacOSX does it in the finder. How do i get the order of the files in my filessystem?

Comment: I think i have to look out for "natural sort"

Comment: Well this is just one example of sort function. You could re-write it to do any kind of sorting. In a nutshell, sort passes 2 of your array elements (a and b) to your sorting function. If it returns less than 0 a will be moved to a lower index than b. If it returns greater than 0, b will be moved to a lower index than a. If it returns 0, a and be retain order with respect to one another but are sorted with respect to other elements.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.sort` takes an optional comparison function ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort)), so you can do:

```
images.sort(function(a, b) {
    // compare a.title to b.title
});
```